# Help with Duplifaces

Tags: mesh

[image]I have used a plane and a diamond shape to duplicate ths diamond on a plane. It has worked successfully using Ctrl+P and duplication>faces however i want to get rid of the big diamond which was used for duplicating, is there a way to get rid of it? I have tried going into: object > apply > make duplicates real but it makes viewport and render slow again.

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to know how to solve this correctly.

As far as I know it is a limitation of the current system and there is no way around it at the moment like shown [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-223506.html?s=c26242a92e9a4d4e34b4cd27b2186a36) and [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/duplication/duplifaces.html)

From my experiments moving the original to another layer or hiding it also hides their duplicates.

1. One workaround is making duplicates real, but that slows things down as you already mentioned.
2. Another workaround as mentioned in the Blender manual is moving the duplicator object's center away to some place it doesn't bother you, and move the duplicate original along with it to the same position. It wont really hide it but you can move it out of view.
3. The way I generally do this is by using a particle system instead, make it emit from faces with the *Unborn* and *Died* option enabled in the *Render* panel, and manually match the particle count to the object's number of faces. This way you can hide the original particle, move to another layer or even put in anther scene without ill effects.

Maybe someone here has a better workaround than this, and I sure would love to hear it.

Comment: I think i might have found a solution. I was curious and just did a render test, before and after making duplicates real, and i got the same render times for both before and after. Ofcourse after making duplicates real, it got rid of the parent, and i used Ctrl + J to join up all the duplicates into one. And it works at the same speed in viewport and render as it did before.

Comment: Yes, that works too, but you loose all the advantages of having duplicates or instances in the first place, like editability, modularity, memory savings and optimization